# Working by subdomain in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, subdomain

I have a website by this domain www.example.com that give some services to users
i want to have a subdomain like this www.external.example.com for giving provided service on www.example.com but just in different view
In other word i want to all controller and action that is accessible on example.com accessible and work in external.example.com too
I just want this subdomain to detect and change my layout(masterpage) to show diffrent view to user

a thing like this in _viewstart.cshtml

```
@{

    // indecate which layout must show
    if (request from external.example.com)
    {
        // for external load
        Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_ExternalLayout.cshtml";
    }
    else
    {
            // for normal load
            Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
    }
}
```

how can do this?

Answer (score 0):

Find the subdomain:

```
var url = Request.Url;

string subdomain = string.Empty;

if (url.HostNameType == UriHostNameType.Dns)
{
    string host = url.Host;
    if (host.Split('.').Length > 2)
    {
        int lastIndex = host.LastIndexOf(".");
        int index = host.IndexOf(".");
        subdomain = index.Equals(lastIndex) ? string.Empty : host.Substring(0, index);
    }
}
```

Then, write some code to select the proper layout:

```
switch(subdomain)
{
    case "external":
        Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_ExternalLayout.cshtml";
        break;

    default:
        Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
        break;
}
```